# Flipping (about the x axis) an image in a CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

A friend and I are trying to find a way to rotate an image being played on a CSS animation. Every time the image  changes direction, the image itself will rotate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

.a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;

  position: relative;
  animation-name: box;
  animation-duration: 10s;
 
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;

.a { }
.left { transform: scaleX(-1); }
/*  
width: 12px;
height:12px;
*/
}

}

@keyframes box {
  0%   { left: var(--rando0); top: var(--rando1);}
  25%  { left: var(--rando2); top: var(--rando3);}
  50%  { left: var(--rando4); top: var(--rando5);}
  75%  { left: var(--rando6); top: var(--rando7);}
  100% { left: var(--rando8); top: var(--rando9);}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image.gif" alt="imagehere" class='a left'  class='character'>


<script>
const root = document.querySelector(":root"); // we first get the root element
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  root.style.setProperty(`--rando${i}`, `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1}px`);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this but so far nothing has worked so far. Can someone please help us? Thanks

Let me know if I need to do anything to the code to make it work better (or simplified).

Comment: Have you looked at [`rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/rotate)?

Comment: Are you using some sort of pre-processor because your CSS looks odd - the keyframes won't be picked up.

Comment: How much rotation are you wanting. And you might like to look at transforrm translate as a way of doing the movements rather than top and left.

Comment: Sorry I meant to flip the image across it's y axis, not to rotate it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need html syntax structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        
        .a {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;

            position: relative;
            animation-name: box;
            animation-duration: 10s;

            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-direction: alternate;
        }

        .left {
            transform: scaleX(-1);
        }


        @keyframes box {
            0% {
                left: var(--rando0);
                top: var(--rando1);
            }

            25% {
                left: var(--rando2);
                top: var(--rando3);
            }

            50% {
                left: var(--rando4);
                top: var(--rando5);
            }

            75% {
                left: var(--rando6);
                top: var(--rando7);
            }

            100% {
                left: var(--rando8);
                top: var(--rando9);
            }
        }
    </style>

</head>

<img src="f.png" alt="imagehere" class='a left' class='character'>

<script>
    const root = document.querySelector(":root");
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        root.style.setProperty(`--rando${i}`, `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1}px`);
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but I need the image to flip about it's x axis every time it changes direction. This example seems to only permanently flip the image, regardless if it changes direction or not.